# Web scraping with cheerio not working with some elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, web-crawler, cheerio

I just started learning about web scraping and I found this tutorial:
https://www.mundojs.com.br/2020/05/25/criando-um-web-scraper-com-nodejs/

It works fine, however I'm trying to get different elements from the same webpage: https://ge.globo.com/futebol/brasileirao-serie-a/

With the group of classes of the tutorial it brings all the elements with the selected class, but with other classes it doesn't work:

[image]

As can be seen all fifty elements with the class `ranking-item-wrapper` are returned, but if I select elements with the class `lista-jogos__jogo` it doesn't return anything:

[image]
[image]

I don't get why I'm getting this error, since I'm doing exectly the same thing as it is done in the tutorial.

Here is a short version of the code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const url = 'https://ge.globo.com/futebol/brasileirao-serie-a/';

axios(url).then(response => {
  const html = response.data;
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  console.log($('.ranking-item-wrapper')) // => tutorial class
  console.log('***')
  console.log($('.lista-jogos__jogo')) // => class that I'm using
}).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw the answer from @Bradley and although it explained what was happening, it doesn't provide a solution. He was correct in saying the elements are being appended with Javascript. There are a few ways we can handle this to get the same data.

I saw your response regarding waiting for the elements to load, this is possible using something like JSDOM/Puppeteer but it's completely overkill and would most likely result in bugs from unsupported JS and/or a massive CPU/Memory overhead in comparison to something like Cheerio.

*Typically*, in my experience, the reason the elements are being appended with Javascript is that the data is being pulled externally from an API, this is a simple fix because you can just check the networking tools to see an XHR request which gets the data, usually it's in an easier-to-parse format too because it's being pulled from an API (JSON). This is very common now a days with all the client-side progressive web apps.

The alternative is the data is hard-coded in a site script which can be split out into a parsable format. You might see this on progressive web apps that take advantage of server-side rendering for the SEO benefit.

I found the data is coming from an external API which is returning JSON data. The URL Is:

https://api.globoesporte.globo.com/tabela/d1a37fa4-e948-43a6-ba53-ab24ab3a45b1/fase/fase-unica-campeonato-brasileiro-2021/rodada/38/jogos/

You will need to request this URL instead and parse the JSON response to get the data that you need, rather than using Cheerio.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's exactly what I was looking for. I had already tried JSDOM and it wasn't working the way I need. Puppeteer was my first attempt, even before Cheerio, it kind of worked, but with a lot of little issues. Your answer made my work a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like those elements are being added with JavaScript when the page is loaded.

If you inspect the page in your browser with JavaScript disabled you can see that those elements don't exist, so they also wont exist when you pull down the page with Cheerio.

Comment: Yes, I kept digging and figured that out, so I chose another website to get the information I need. But is there a way I can force cheerio to wait for those elements to be inserted to the DOM? I thought about setTimeout, but maybe there is a more trustworthy way to do that.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, here is a quote from the [Cheerio website](https://cheerio.js.org/):

"Cheerio parses markup and provides an API for traversing/manipulating the resulting data structure. It does not interpret the result as a web browser does. Specifically, it does not produce a visual rendering, apply CSS, load external resources, or execute JavaScript which is common for a SPA (single page application)."

It does recommend using things like [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) or [JSDom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) for that kind of functionality however.